# Orthogonal matching pursuit regression - am I using it wrong?

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn, regression, regularized

I am trying out this method as a regularized regression, as an alternative to lasso and elastic net. I have 40k data points and 40 features. Lasso selects 5 features, and orthogonal matching pursuit selects only 1.

What could be causing this? Am I using omp the wrong way? Perhaps it is not meant to be used as a regression. Please let me know if you can thing of anything else I may be doing wrong.

Comment: I can't  help as I don't know a thing about scikit-learn, but you need to provide us with some more details. What is the code that you're running? Can you provide us with a small dataset that reproduces your problem?

Comment: You question is a much better guess for http://stats.stackexchange.com/ - Good luck!

Comment: Please post complete, runnable code and dataset. The question is impossible to answer otherwise.

Comment: What are you setting as the target sparsity when you create the omp object? Do you get an error/warning when you run the code for the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orthogonal Matching Pursuit seems a bit broken, or at least very sensitive to input data, as implemented in scikit-learn.

Example:

```
import sklearn.linear_model 
import sklearn.datasets 
import numpy

X, y, w = sklearn.datasets.make_regression(n_samples=40000, n_features=40, n_informative=10, coef=True, random_state=0)

clf1 = sklearn.linear_model.LassoLarsCV(fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, max_n_alphas=1e6) 
clf1.fit(X, y)

clf2 = sklearn.linear_model.OrthogonalMatchingPursuitCV(fit_intercept=True, normalize=False)
clf2.fit(X, y)

# this is 1e-10, LassoLars is basically exact on this data 
print numpy.linalg.norm(y - clf1.predict(X))

# this is 7e+8, OMP is broken
print numpy.linalg.norm(y - clf2.predict(X))
```

Fun experiments:

- There are a bunch of canned datasets in `sklearn.datasets`.  Does OMP fail on all of them?  Apparently, it works okay on the diabetes dataset...
- Is there any combination of parameters to `make_regression` that would generate data that OMP works for?  Still looking for that one... 100 x 100 and 100 x 10 fail in the same way.

Comment: Maybe then this should be posted as an Issue at the [scikit-learn github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn)

Comment: @JoãoAlmeida: Yes, probably.  I want to be sure it is a bug and not how  OMP is supposed to work though.  I'd try some more simple synthetic data first.

Comment: @BaronYugovich: Do you have any more questions about this?  If I've ansered your question please remember to accept and award the bounty.